My postgres database startup has been running for almost 2 days+
I messed up my pgsql database by mistakenly deleting files on pg_wal, it resulted to a non-recoverable state (with no backups to restore with) so i decided to run the pg_resetwal.exe -f (considering the data loss).
After resetwal, I ran: postgres -D /u01/pgsql/15/data, and since wednesday (12/18/2024) and up to this date (12/20/2024) the startup is still running? Was this normal? How long does it usually take to finish starting-up? Or Should i terminate the running PID for the startup and rebuild the database from scratch?
Sample logs as of date:
2024-12-20 08:06:46.367 PST [826063] LOCATION:  LogCheckpointStart, xlog.c:6099
2024-12-20 08:06:46.477 PST [826063] LOG:  00000: checkpoint complete: wrote 2 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.102 s, sync=0.001 s, total=0.110 s; sync files=2, longest=0.001 s, average=0.001 s; distance=16380 kB, estimate=16383 kB
2024-12-20 08:06:46.477 PST [826063] LOCATION:  LogCheckpointEnd, xlog.c:6188


the startup is still running? Was this normal? - no. If what you mean is postgres started and is still running - then it looks like you simply started postgres but the process didn't daemonize (background) and your terminal is just the foreground instance of postgres running. If you have lost the data, it may be better to start over, wipe the data directory and reinitialize postgres to ensure there are no remnants in data that are causing problems. It would help to know what OS you are running.
